iisnode encountered an error when processing the request on Plesk
I published my STRAPI application on Plesk. But when I go to the URL I encounter an error like this:

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.
In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.
You may get additional information about this error condition by logging stdout and stderr of the node.exe process.To enable logging, set the system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled configuration setting to 'true' (current value is 'false').

I gave full control to IIS_IUSRS from the security section in the directory where the file is located and restarted the application from the IIS Manager section. But it didn't work.
my web.config file:
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <iisnode loggingEnabled="false" />
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

server.js file:
const { createStrapi } = require('@strapi/strapi');
const app = createStrapi({ distDir: './dist' });
app.start();

